# Как в code::blocks указать библиотеку?

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

Хочу например создать программу с glfw3, но появляется вот такое окно, в которое нужно вписать то ли include то ли lib, я не пойму как правильно это сделать. И ещё одна просьба, если я к проекту ещё хочу библиотеку подключить то как мне это сделать?
[image: не найдена либа]

Comment: вам нужно выбрать путь к корневой папке, которая содержит glfw (в этой папке должны находится папки include и lib).  все ведь написано.

Comment: Но в линуксе же в /usr/include находятся заголовки, а в /usr/lib находятся библиотеки. Такого каталога glfw, в котором содержаться эти каталоги, нет.

Comment: [гайд по установке glfw](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html)

Comment: Очень не советую пользоваться в кодеблоках шаблонами проектов для конкретных библиотек. Это все прекрасно настраивается руками в пустом проекте.